# sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Люди помогите!!!
Как исправить эту ошибку "sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied"?
Когда я пишу:

`sudo su`

Выдают ошибка

`sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied`

Comment: Когда эта ошибка возникает? Уточните вопрос

Comment: вообще-то для запуска оболочки от имени целевого пользователя лучше выполнять не `$ sudo su`, а `$ sudo -i`. это так, к слову. лучше, конечно, не делать ни того, ни другого.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобв использовать sudo Вам необходимо находится в файле sudoers

Comment: Конкретизируйте ответ. Пока что это не является ответом.